# It it possible to determine what function a bound function is wrapping?

Tags: node.js

I've written a set of library functions that operate based on a set of rules that are added during set up. Rules are associated with functions and are applied when those functions are passed in as parameters later. It all works fine except that if someone adds rules, then binds the function when passing it in (e.g. `this.func.bind(this)`) this is a brand new function that can't be tracked back to the original function.

I've tried reading the docs and as far as I can determine, there's no way to determine the function a bound function "points to". Additionally, any properties I attempt to set on the function get lost as well as they are not copied across to the new bound function.

Is there any way around this? It's not a deal breaker I suppose, but I just know it'll be a potential headache for someone down the road when they inevitably forget they should bind functions before adding rules (if they're going to do it) and so I was hoping someone might have a work-around available.